# respresent more columns value in one chart of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, charts

i want to make one application in which there is a table with columns

- Dustbin no.
- January
- February
  ......
- December

there are more than one dustbin_no

now in chart i want to display chart of dustbin_no selected by user in drop down box.

in chart code of asp.net how could i use more than one columns

in chart

x-axis:january,february,march..............

y-axis:how many times dustbin is fulled

just for information in data of each mounth data given is number of times dustbin fulled

like

dustbin no  january  february ........

1            45       55          65

here is some code

```
<chartareas>
    <asp:ChartArea BackColor="NavajoWhite" BackGradientStyle="LeftRight" 
        Name="ChartArea1" ShadowOffset="5">
        <AxisY Title="Dustbin_no">
        </AxisY>

        <AxisX Title="January" IsLabelAutoFit="True">
            <LabelStyle Angle="-90" Interval="1" />
        </AxisX>
    </asp:ChartArea>
</chartareas>
```

pls help

Comment: go through this article http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072909-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think asp.net chart doesn't  support chart with more than one column. But there is a control collection by devexpress. It has some advance controls for asp.net

[Link of Devexpress site](http://www.devexpress.com/)